# Readline on closed filehandle

Tags: perl

I'm using this sub for my prgram to wait up to several hours for a task to finish what it's doing on windows.
When the windows task finishes, it updates a string in a text file to let the Linux script know that Windows is done.

I get this error while it's running:
readline() on closed filehandle

Here is the sub

```
my $numberOfChecks = 28;
my $sleepTime = 900;
my $communicationsFile = "/home/user/ICAhome/Win_To_Linux_ComFile.txt";
my $winBuild = "1";

sub waitForWindowsBuild {
    while ($numberOfChecks-- $$ $winBuild == "1"){
        open (MYFILE, $communicationsFile);

        while (<MYFILE>){
            chomp;
            if ($_ eq $buildValue){
                $winBuild="1";
            }

            sleep($sleepTime);
        }

        close(MYFILE);
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `open` succeeds. For example,

```
open (MYFILE, $communicationsFile)
   or die("Can't open $communicationsFile: $!\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll add that. Is it possible this would crash a server if it tried opening a file 20 times and giving this error every time?

Comment: "Crash" is ambiguous. `die` will exit the script, if that's what you mean. Feel free to do something other than `die`.

Comment: I ran this last night without the die, and when I got back this morning, the server was down and the program had given me about 20 of these errors.

Comment: Sure, why not. No matter how many times you trying to open a file that doesn't exist or you don't have permission to, it's going to fail.

Comment: Note that `readline() on unopened filehandle` is just a warning. It doesn't cause the program to exit.